# Moving from MySQL 5.5 to GAE with cloud SQL : Microtime support?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.5, microtime, mysql-5.6

### Background:

I have a project running on [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/) with PHP 5.4.10 and MySQL 5.5

Due to the high performance requirements the Project has most of its business logic in Stored MySQL procedures, and for debugging and logging purposes each procedure stores its own runtime - the millisecond it began executing.

Since MySQL 5.5 does not support milliseconds I ended up compiling my own UDF that allowed me to accurately store the current unix timestamp with milliseconds. ([See MICROTIME on Github](https://github.com/JohannesMP/MySQL-udf-microtime)).

If a flag is set for a procedure to write to the log, that runtime value can be used to:

1. calculate how long the procedure has been running at the time it wrote to the log. Example:
    `INSERT INTO Log(call_time,run_time,message) VALUES(@t, MICROTIME()-@t, @m)`
2. group log entries for each instance of the procedure (since multiple instances of a procedure are running concurrently). Example: 
   `SELECT * FROM Log ORDER BY call_time`

Basically, Microtime support has been critical for this project.

---

### Question:

With the PHP version of Google's App engine having matured a good deal over the last year I'm considering moving the project onto GAE with Google Cloud SQL.

From what I've read it seems that Google Cloud SQL:

1. Does not allow UDF's
2. Is based on MySQL 5.5

Is that correct? Are there any potential workarounds I could use on Google Cloud SQL that would allow me to use microseconds?

For example, MySQL 5.6 seems to offer microsecond support. Is there any way to use MySQL 5.6 on Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. Google Cloud SQL is based on MySQL 5.5, and UDF is not supported. 
Unfortunately MySQL 5.6 isn't available on Cloud SQL at the moment.